# Python - Trying to print json data from API results in a certain way

Tags: python, json, api, post, parameters

Right now I have:

```
import json

api_key = '123456'
url = "https://safebrowsing.googleapis.com/v4/threatMatches:find"
payload = {'client': {'clientId': "mycompany", 'clientVersion': "0.1"},
           'threatInfo': {'threatTypes': ["SOCIAL_ENGINEERING", "MALWARE"],
                          'platformTypes': ["ANY_PLATFORM"],
                          'threatEntryTypes': ["URL"],
                          'threatEntries': [{'url': "http://malware.testing.google.test/testing/malware/"}]}}
params = {'key': api_key}
r = requests.post(url, params=params, json=payload)
# Print response
print(r)
print(r.json())
```

Which gives me the results of:

```
<Response [200]>
{'matches': [{'threatType': 'MALWARE', 'platformType': 'ANY_PLATFORM', 'threat': {'url': 'http://malware.testing.google.test/testing/malware/'}, 'cacheDuration': '300s', 'threatEntryType': 'URL'}]}
```

I want to print it more nicely / drop some data so it looks like:

```
Url: 'http://malware.testing.google.test/testing/malware/'
ThreatType: 'MALWARE'
PlatformType: 'ANY_PLATFORM'
```

But every time I try something I just keep getting positional argument errors

Edit: Having more than 2 urls submitted gives the following output

```
{'matches': [{'threatType': 'MALWARE', 'platformType': 'ANY_PLATFORM', 'threat': {'url': 'http://malware.testing.google.test/testing/malware/'}, 'cacheDuration': '300s', 'threatEntryType': 'URL'}, {'threatType': 'MALWARE', 'platformType': 'ANY_PLATFORM', 'threat': {'url': 'http://malware.testing.google.test/testing/malware/'}, 'cacheDuration': '300s', 'threatEntryType': 'URL'}]}
```

Comment: Can you get more than one match?

Comment: If you mean can enter 2+ URLs then yes, and it just adds on to the very end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A defensive approach:

```
for match in r.json().get('matches', []):
    print(f'URL: {match.get("threat", {}).get("url", "Unknown URL")}')
    print(f'threatType: {match.get("threatType", "Unknown ThreadType")}')
    print(f'platformType: {match.get("platformType", "Unknown PlatformType")}')
```

Comment: Thanks! that's perfect you are a lifesaver!